# Understanding import and scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-3.6

I am a noob to python and I am trying to understand how the import statement works.

I am running python 3.6.
I have IDLE working.

My test directory is setup like

directory:test_py

In the directory test_py I have files
test_calc.py,button.py,graphics.py

graphics.py is a graphics library.

My main program is in **test_calc.py**.

In **test_calc.py** I use **from graphics import ***.  Its the first line

button.py  is a module that contains a class definition, Button.
It also uses the graphics library graphics.py.

The main program in test_calc.py uses the Button class.
The Button class definition also calls Point, a function from the graphics library.

I thought the call to create a Button object would be able to use the graphcs
library from the statement **from graphics import*** in test_calc.py, but it cant.

button.py also needs a  **from graphics import *** to access the graphics  library functions.

Is there a way I can have just the **from graphics import* ** in test_calc.py 
and have the Button class also see the graphics library
module and objects without have to also import it in button.py?

I have spent a easy 8hrs reading and trying to figure this out.
Any help is appreciated.

#### here is the complete test_calc.py file

```
from graphics import *
from button import *

def __createButtons(win):
    #create a list of buttons
    bSpecs = [(2,1,'0'), (3,1,'.'),
              (1,2,'1'), (2,2,'2'), (3,2,'3'), (4,2,'+'), (5,2,'-'),
              (1,3,'4'), (2,3,'5'), (3,3,'6'), (4,3,'*'), (5,3,'/'),
              (1,4,'7'), (2,4,'8'), (3,4,'9'), (4,4,'<-'), (5,4,'C')] 

buttons = []

for (cx,cy,label) in bSpecs:
    buttons.append(Button(win, Point(cx,cy), .75,.75,label))

###create larger = button
buttons.append(Button(win, Point(4.5,1), 1.75, .75, "="))

#activate all buttons
for b in buttons:
    b.activate()

def main():
    #create the window for the calculator
    win = GraphWin("Calculator")
    win.setCoords(0,0,6,7)
    win.setBackground("slategray")
    win= win
    __createButtons(win)

main()
```

## here is the beginning of button.py

## The Point function from graphics library is not available to Button without this statement

```
from graphics import * 
class Button:

def __init__(self, win, center, width, height, label):
        w,h = width/2.0, height/2.0
        x,y = center.getX(), center.getY()
        self.xmax, self.xmin = x+w, x-w
        self.ymax, self.ymin = y+h, y-h

        #Point function from graphics library
        p1 = Point(self.xmin,self.ymin)
        p2 = Point(self.xmax, self.ymax)
```

Comment: You may create better questions if you read [ask] (and also [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, there is no way to do that.

`graphics.py` is out of scope of `button.py`, because `test_calc.py` imported graphics and `test_calc.py` is in scope of `button.py`.

However, if you really want to save an extra line, you can just remove `from graphics import *` from `test_calc.py` because `button.py` already imported `graphics.py`.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this. If this worked the way you want, you'd break namespacing and scope implicitly within `button`, not just explicitly in `test_calc`.

The scope of a module (used by all things defined in that module) is defined by what it imports, and what it defines (and in poor design cases, by things monkey=patched in later). Adding in things from "stuff defined in the things that imported me" is a terrible idea.

The correct solution here is to just do:

```
# If a package, explicit relative imports avoid checking the whole of sys.path
from .graphics import *

# IF not a package, use plain names without leading .s
from graphics import *
```

at the top of your `button.py` file, so it actually specifies where it expects to get the APIs from (ideally, you explicitly list the names to use, not just `*`, which helps static checking code determine if all your names are defined, helps maintainers figure out where specific names came from, and avoids the risk of two modules providing the same name and stomping all over each other). Since you've already done this, you're golden; you can just omit the import of `graphics` stuff in `test_calc.py` (assuming `test_calc.py` itself doesn't use it).

If, for some insane reason, this really is necessary, the simplest way to do it is to bypass `import` semantics and explicitly `eval` the code for `button` in the same scope that includes the `graphics` stuff. In `test_calc.py`, after doing `from graphics import *`, you'd explicitly `open` and `read` the contents of `button.py` (into, for example, `button_source`) then do:

```
eval(compile(button_source, button_path, 'exec'), globals())
```

which would compile and evaluate the source code of `button.py` using `test_calc`'s global scope (which includes `graphics` stuff now), so the newly defined stuff would be defined in `test_calc`'s globals, and see all the stuff defined there as its "native scope" too.

Comment: Ok I removed the import graphic statement from test_calc.py, left it in  button.py and sure enough it works. But test_calc.py does  have a call to Point which is in the graphics library. But since button.py imported the graphics library and the graphics objects would be in the button.py scope how does the test_calc module see the graphic library objects?

Comment: @1amdadmt: Well, to be clear, it would be best to do the import in both places, if `graphics` is used in both places. The reason it works without that import in `test_calc` is because you didn't define `__all__` in `button`  (nor alias the names you imported from `graphics` to add a leading underscore), so when you do `from button import *` you get all top level names in `button`, which includes all imported names too. A good practice is to  define `__all__` with only the names that are part of `button`s public API, to avoid this excessive import that can mislead users of `button`.